# Select a date and format output

Tags: sas

Below is my code of 5 lines. When I run the first 3 lines I get a date output of 21042 and would like it displayed/formatted as 8/11/2017.  I am having trouble with the format part (line 4) and need help with it. My code is:

```
PROC SQL;
select max (Load_DT) as max_date
from in.db_tb    
Format max_date yymmdd10.;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `format` statement in the select part of the query.

```
data db_tb;
  load_dt = today();
run;


PROC SQL;
select max (Load_DT) as max_date format yymmdd10.
from db_tb    ;
quit;
```

Note your stated preference (8/11/2017) does not match the format you use in your code (2017-08-11).  `MMDDYY10.` is the format that you'd want for that.

Comment: up until today, I thought it had to be format=yymmdd10. for SQL. Apparently both work though, so I learned something new :)

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that after I wrote it and ran it successfully, and thought "I thought that was format=yymmdd10., huh guess I was wrong"...